# Find how many users viewed any page within a section of pages

Tags: google-analytics

Site structure is simple:

`/menu`
`/blog`
`/photos`

Each of these "sections" have many pages below them. All of these pages follow the url structure: pages under `/menu` have the url `/menu/nameofthething`, etc.

**How do I answer the question: "of all of the users to our website, how many users ever view any page under `/blog`?"**

"Content Drilldown" allows you to see page views for a section like `/menu` or `/blog` but it doesn't appear to give me any data that would allow me to calculate that from page views into users.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by users? For the most part it is calculated by pageviews and unique pageviews (GA sets a cookie that lasts 30 minutes  and will combine multiple pageviews from that single cookie into one).

Comment: Why the heck is this tagged with `regex`?

Comment: Make custom report with: users and "content drilldown" in "customization".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom segment of your users, who have visited a given page or set of pages, or a segment of sessions, that contain a visit of selected page(s). (Look for Conditions tab under Advanced group of New segment dialog.) You can apply this segment to your reports, e.g. Audience reports in your case, which will give you number of users for this particular segment and selected time period.